# Where is the source of the formula $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \bigl(j+\frac{1}{2}\bigr)^{n-1}\frac{2^{j+1/2}}{\binom{2j+1}{j+1/2}}$ for an integer sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, additive-combinatorics, integer-sequences, closed-form-expressions, infinite-sequences

The infinite series representation
\begin{equation}
\frac1\pi\sum_{j=0}^\infty \biggl(j+\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^{n-1}\frac{2^{j+1/2}}{\binom{2j+1}{j+1/2}}, \quad n\ge0
\end{equation}
for the positive integer sequence
\begin{gather}
1, 1, 2, 7, 35, 226, 1787, 16717, 180560, 2211181, 30273047,\\
458186752, 7596317885, 136907048461, 2665084902482,\\
55726440112987, 1245661569161135, 29642264728189066,\\
748158516941653967, 19962900431638852297,\\
561472467839585937560, 16602088291822017588121, \dotsc
\end{gather}
appears at https://oeis.org/A014307.

[image: Screenshot of the site https://oeis.org/A014307]

But there is no reference given for this series representation.

Could you please help find a source (such as a paper, a monograph, a book, a handbook, and the like, but not a website) including this series representation or its proof? Thank you very much.

By the way, I established a closed-form expression
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^kS(n,k) (2k-1)!!, \quad n\ge0
\end{equation}
and others for the above sequence, where $S(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a reference, but it is not hard to prove the result. You want to prove that if
$$\left(\frac{e^x}{2-e^x}\right)^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
then
$$a_n=\frac 1\pi\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(j+\frac 12\right)^{n-1}\frac{2^{j+1/2}}{\binom{2j+1}{j+1/2}}. $$
I am not a fan of non-integer binomial coefficients, so I write
$$\frac 1{\binom{2j+1}{j+1/2}}=\frac{\pi(j+1/2)(1/2)_j}{2^{2j+1}j!}.$$
Here,
$(a)_j=a(a+1)\dotsm(a+j-1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol. So we want to prove
$$a_n=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(j+\frac 12\right)^{n}\frac{(1/2)_j}{j!2^{j+1/2}}.$$
Now simply plug one series into the other and change order of integration. I get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)_j}{j!2^{j+1/2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(j+\frac 12\right)^{n} \frac{x^n}{n!}
=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)_j}{j!2^{j+1/2}}e^{(j+1/2)x}.
$$
Now we are reduced to the binomial series
$$\frac 1{(1-t)^{1/2}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)_j}{j!}\,t^j$$
(with $t=e^{x}/2$).

(It would have been more pedagogical to write this backwards: First use the binomial theorem to expand your function in a series of $e^x$ and then use
the Taylor series of the exponential function.)

Comment: Thank @Hjalmar Rosengren for your answer! I added the factor $\frac{1}{\pi}$ to my question.

Comment: I believe that the proof(s) of the infinite series representation in my question existed somewhere. So I asked for a reference to cite it.

Comment: Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1.

Comment: Thanks for thanking me in your paper!

Comment: @https://mathoverflow.net/users/10846/hjalmar-rosengren You deserve it. Thank you very much once again.